# how to hide overridden div borders? if two div override then remove borders from overridden area only

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

I have two div which override each other. I want to remove border from overridden area only.
Please have look at sample code below

```
<div  style="width:100px; height:20px; background-color:#5475b1;border: 2px solid;"></div>
<div  style="width:150px; height:200px; background-color: #5475b1;border: 2px solid;"></div>
```

this code will output as:

[image]

but I want output as:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Note: I am working on drop-down menu. first div is actually used for menu name and second div is used for menu list.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to that. But basic mechanic is similar. One way is:

1. Tab element has no border on bottom.
2. Menu element slide up under tab element as high as border is thick.

See (quick and dirty) Example with comments in code:

```css
nav div {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
}

.tab {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    /* no border bottom */
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    /* tab to foreground*/
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu {
    width: 300px;
    /* border all arround */
    border: 4px solid red;
    /* element in background */
    z-index: 9;
    /* move menu up = slid under tab */
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <div class="tab">Menutab</div>

    <div class="menu">
        Menuitem<br>
        Menuitem<br>
        Menuitem<br>
        Menuitem<br>
        Menuitem<br>
        ...
    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
#divTop {
  height:20px; 
  width:100px;
  background: #5475b1; 
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}
 
 #divBottom {
  height:200px;
  width:150px; 
  background: #5475b1; 
  clear: both; 
  border: 2px solid black;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="divTop"  ></div>
    <div id ="divBottom" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```